# Can some form of backpropagation be applied to an reinforcement algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, agent, reinforcement-learning

I was wondering: If multiple agents were trained in a reinforcement setting, would there be a way to let them teach each other?

More specifically let's assume a typical gym class of several children: Some are good in task A, some in B, some in C. Very often, the best peer shows the others how it is done. They use the movement of the "master" as a guide to improving their own movements.

Applied to NN, several could be trained in different environments, providing different learning histories. Those that perform better in a subtask of the overall performance measurement function might teach the others how to improve their performance in this space.

So if all algorithms are put through 100 cycles of reinforcement, they learn different strengths. A benchmark can then be used to evaluate who is performing best in several subtasks. Each time, the others get to "watch" what the best peer did and then use e.g. back-propagation to adapt their behavior to more closely match that of the best-peer.

I am just starting to learn about the reinforcement algorithms currently being SOTA so I am unsure if the inner workings of those algorithms support something *like* backpropagation or if they could support is straight out of the box.

Comment: Off-topic here - more appropriate for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) sister sites.

Comment: There are plenty of Data Science related questions in SO, and I find it hard to select the right sister site in the SE network for quiet a while now. there is also an ai.stackexchange, but that one is basically dormant. I believe (on a meta level), there needs to be some consolidation of these sites to make one strong commonuity on all things data based digital knowledge, be it AI, NN, data science or what have it.

Comment: I think your question title is loosely related with your actual question. Backpropagation can be applied in reinforcement learning algorithms. In fact, there are many cases where some kind of backpropagation has been combined with RL methods. However, it seems your question is more relared with some kind of transfer learning between agents, right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not programming related but rather AI related